# Marshall without xmlns

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd, marshalling

After marshalling my xsd I have something like this in xml

```
<elements xmlns="http://myNameSpace.com/hello">
  <element>
   ...
  </element>
</element>
```

And I want to have this **without**

> xmlns="http://myNameSpace.com/hello"

I've tried some things, but I don't know what should I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xmlns` attribute is appearing because there is namespace qualification specified in the metadata (most likely via the `@XmlSchema` annotation on the `package-info` class.  Removing this metadata will cause the output to no longer be namespace qualified.

**Note:**
If your model was generated from an XML Schema doing this would cause the JAXB model to no longer work with XML documents that conform to that schema.